# Как сделать аналог FlipView с эффектами?

Tags: xaml, uwp

Надо сделать подобие тура при первом входе в приложение. Проблема в том, что элементы должны по-разному анимироваться.
Имеем 4 экрана с фоновыми картинками, текстом и логотипом. Картинки и тексты разные, логотип неизменный.
При свайпе надо плавно менять картинку фейдингом, текст должен сдвигаться в сторону и уступать место новому тексту. Логотип должен висеть постоянно. 
С логотипом всё понятно. Текст вроде как будет именно через FlipView сдвигаться, но как совместить это с фоновыми картинками?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось сделать.
Для всего, что должно сдвигаться делаем FlipViewItem-ы, фоновую картинку меняем через Behaviors в соответствии с FlipView.SelectedItem. Пока только так придумал.